# Is it incorrect to modify a temporary?

Tags: c++

In C++98/03/11 the following code is valid:

```
std::string meow() { return "meow"; }

int main()
{
    meow().append("purr");
    return 0;
}
```

Since the temporary dies at the semi-colon, this should be safe right?

Comment: If you would like to prevent this kind of behavior you can actually return a `const std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not incorrect and it is useful to do this in certain circumstances.

Suppose I have a vector with a lot of data and I want to clear the data and the memory..

```
{ 
   std::vector< int >().swap( myVec );
}
```

will clear the memory for certain. `myVec.clear()` will probably only change the logical size back to 0.

As I showed in a previous question you can use it like this:

```
class Foo
{
   public:
       Foo& operator+=( Foo const& ); // implement
       Foo operator+( Foo const& rhs ) const
       {
          return Foo( *this ) += rhs;
       }
 };
```

The implementation there modifies a temporary then returns it by value (r-value reference in C++11, by value in C++03).

Obviously with r-value references you have more examples like in your case you can return     `meow().append( "purr")`

Comment: I know this is just an example, but in case anyone doesn't know.. in C++11 you can use `shrink_to_fit`

Comment: @NeilKirk `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding.

Comment: No but it hints to compiler. We trust the compiler to make other optimizations when it wants to, why not this one?

Comment: @NeilKirk It isn't really a compiler issue; it's a library issue. If you want to make 100% sure that the memory is freed, then the swap is still the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal, and useful:

```
class Foo{
    int *data;
public:
    Foo(){data=new int[100];}
    Foo(const Foo& other){ //copy ctor
        if(other.data!=nullptr){
            data=new int[100]; //make a new array
            for(unsigned i=0; i<100; ++i) //
                data[i]=other.data[i];   //fill it using content of other
        }
    }
    Foo(Foo&& other){ //move ctor
        data=other.data; /* obvioulsly grab the other's pointer :)
                          * other is a temporary, so we don't have to
                          * allocate new array and copy other's content,
                          * because other is going to disappear soon.
                          */
        other.data=nullptr; /* Without this line, other and *this
                             * have the same pointer!
                             * When *this or other gets destroyed,
                             * it frees the data; second object
                             * doesn't know about the deletion, 
                             * and may still want to use the data,
                             * causing undefined behavior by using fryed memory.
                             */
    }
    ~Foo(){delete[] data;} //frees data
};
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Please elaborate!

Comment: Nope. Deleting pointer which is equal to `nullptr` does nothing :)

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Have you any idea what else can I improve?